# Two Table Left join But if i got extra row In Table then it should be null

Tags: mysql

### ```
   Table A                  Table B
```

```
   id  type_id  amount        id   type_id   amount
   1     2       5000         1      4        2000
   2     4       2000         2      2        3000
                              3      2        2000
```

Now i am going to left join Table A to table B

```
SELECT a.amount, b.amount
FROM tableA a
left JOIN tableB b on b.type_id=a.type_id
```

### It show result something like that

```
        amount               amount
          5000                 2000
          2000                 3000
          5000                 2000
--------------------------------------------------------
```

### I am trying to get result:

```
   amount              amount
   5000                 2000
   2000                 3000
   NULL                 2000
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: based  on type_id  you can't  .. (in sql)

Comment: So which way i can do that will share with me.

Comment: you could do only using  id (in sql)

Comment: now we can let table-b, type_id as a_id first row value is 1 and rest of the same now @scaisEdge it will be work

Comment: update your question  .. because the comment is not clear  ..and expalin better

Comment: i have post a suggestion as answer  hope is clear

Answer (score 1):

Left join, takes all the elements from the left table, and the matches from the right table. The result will be null for the elements on the right side, if matches are not found.

So try to replace the LEFT JOIN with RIGHT JOIN.

SELECT a.amount, b.amount
FROM tableA a
right JOIN tableB b on b.type_id=a.type_id

---

I tried multiple options, and i think i found a better solution! 
Please try this query:

select a.amount, b.amount from table1 a right join table2 b on b.id = (
    select id from table2 b2
    where b2.type_id = a.type_id
    limit 1
)

Hope it works now.

Comment: left join and right join produce the same result  .. just change te main table  ..

Comment: I tried also like that if they don't match any row then it show null but both are matching.Like if table b has id 3 then it will show null because then don't match with table A